# Cannot declare type in F#, Error FS0010, Error FS3118

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2019

I'm having trouble declaring a type in Visual Studio using F#. As soon as I put the **type** keyword in, I get two errors as soon as I enter the word 'type'.

The error under the `let` keyword in main is
`Error FS3118 Incomplete value or function definition. If this is in an expression, the body of the expression must be indented to the same column as the 'let' keyword.`

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let x = 7

    type Book = { Name: string; Author: string; Rating: int; ISBN: string;}
    
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

The error under the `type` keyword is
`Error    FS0010  Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in expression`

I've been trying to fix this but the main fixes for the FS0010 error are just suggestions to indent the code correctly. I know the code is indented correctly because if I get rid of the type keyword and just execute let x = 7, it works fine.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019. Would love some help on this!

Comment: Type cannot be declared inside a function but only in a namespace or in a module (top-level or not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the type before the function.

The error message could be more helpful

```
type Book = { Name: string; Author: string; Rating: int; ISBN: string;}

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let x = 7
    
    0
```